# Extjs 4.2.1 XTemplate date format for child elements is showing NaN on IE only

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, date-format, extjs4.2

Here is the test data:

```
[{
        id: 1,
        isActive: true,
        documentIdentifier: '00012345',
        sourceSiteName: 'Aviation Industry Ltd.',
        targetSiteName: 'VendorName',
        createDate: '2013-03-06T14:12:03.2341054+02:00',
        archiveEvent: 'Rejected',
        archive: 'PurchaseOrder',
        previousWhatsNewEvents: [{
            id: 2,
            isActive: true,
            documentIdentifier: '00012345',
            sourceSiteName: 'Aviation Industry Ltd.',
            targetSiteName: 'Vendor Name',
            createDate: '2013-03-06T14:12:03.2341054+02:00',
            archiveEvent: 'Approved',
            archive: 'PurchaseOrder',
            isPin: true,
            IsDocumentReadByMe: false,
            IsDocumentReadByOthers: true,
            documentYear: 2013,
            businessDirection: 1 
        }],
        isPin:true,
        IsDocumentReadByMe:false,
        IsDocumentReadByOthers:true,
        documentYear:2013,
        businessDirection:1
    }
```

Here is the template:

```
tpl: [
                    '<div class="n-row-title">',
                        '<div class="n-doc-status n-doc-status-{archiveEvent:this.toLower} n-float-left">&nbsp;</div>',
                        '<span class="n-hmargin-10">{archiveEvent}</span>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="n-clear"></div>',
                    '<div class="n-row-sub-title">{createDate:date("m/d/Y H:i")}</div>',
                    '<div class="n-whatsnew-previous-events">',
                        '<tpl for="previousWhatsNewEvents">',
                            '<div class="n-row-title">',
                                '<div class="n-doc-status n-doc-status-{archiveEvent:this.toLower} n-float-left">&nbsp;</div>',
                                '<span class="n-hmargin-10">{archiveEvent}</span>',
                            '</div>',
                            '<div class="n-clear"></div>',
                            '<div class="n-row-sub-title">{createDate:date("m/d/Y H:i")}</div>',
                        '</tpl>',
                    '</div>',
                    {
                        toLower: function (value) {
                            return value.toLowerCase();
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Here is how Chrome is rendering the template:

[image]

Here is how IE8 is rendering it:

[image]

Any one know of a workaround?

**UPDATE**

Here is my module :

```
Ext.define('XX.model.WhatsNew', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'isActive', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'documentIdentifier', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'sourceSiteName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'targetSiteName', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'createDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' },
        { name: 'archiveEvent', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'archive', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents' },
        { name: 'isPin', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'IsDocumentReadByMe', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'IsDocumentReadByOthers', type: 'boolean' },
        { name: 'documentYear', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'businessDirection', type:'int'}
    ],

    hasMany: {
        model: 'auxClasses.notifications.WhatsNew',
        name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents'
    },

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'api/WhatsNew/'
    }
});
```

The template could not read the date format from the inner previousWhatsNewEvents childs... that made the dates go wrong!!

Comment: Read the docs in Ext.data.Field about `dateFormat`.

Comment: how do I set it in the template?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Could this explain how the exact same template code with the same input string does work for the other dates?

Comment: @rixo It has nothing to do with the template, the model data is incorrect because the native IE date parsing doesn't provide as many formats.

Comment: @AMember So, are you passing the raw data to the template or are you using some models? In that later case, have you configured `previousWhatsNewEvents` as an association?

Comment: found the error : issue was that on the inner iteration (previousWhatsNewEvents) the template could not get the date format from my module

Comment: I have added my module to the question, that explains alot... Is there a better way to do though?

Comment: No, as it explains in the docs, if you don't specify the format you're left to the native browser implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Your association is overridden by the field with the same name. Even if that was not the case, you association would not load the child nodes from the data because its [`associationKey`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association-cfg-associationKey) is not configured (see the class description for an example of what it does).

Then again, if you got there, the data view component probably don't support associations... **Update:** That's wrong, see bellow.

So your fast way out of this is to replace the stock `date` format function with your own, that casts date strings using `Ext.Date.format` instead of `new Date` over which you have no control and that may vary between browsers, as pointed out by Evan.

The trick is that you need a date *input format* to use `Ext.Date.format`. In your template, you'll know the expected format:

```
tpl: [
    '{createDate:this.date}',
    {
        date: function(value) {
            var readFormat = 'c',
                displayFormat = 'm/d/Y H:i',
                date = Ext.Date.parse(value, readFormat);
            return Ext.Date.format(date, displayFormat);
        }
    }
]
```

And you can even think of replacing the `Ext.util.Format.date` function by adding an argument to it:

```
Ext.util.Format.date = function(value, outFormat, inFormat) {
    var date;
    if (value) {
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            date = value;
        } else if (inFormat) {
            date = Ext.Date.parse(value, inFormat);
        } else {
            // backward compatibility
            date = new Date(value);
        }
        return Ext.Date.format(date, outFormat);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};
```

**Update**

After further investigation, it appears that data view do in fact support model associations: the view's [`prepareData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/AbstractView.html#Ext-view-AbstractView-method-prepareData) method calls [`getAssociatedData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-getAssociatedData) on the model. So, as pointed by Even again, the cleanest solution is probably to configure your association correctly.

That means removing this field:

```
fields: [
    ...
    { name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents' },
    ...
]
```

Adding the [`associationKey`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association-cfg-associationKey) option:

```
hasMany: {
    model: 'auxClasses.notifications.WhatsNew',
    name: 'previousWhatsNewEvents',
    associationKey: 'previousWhatsNewEvents'
}
```

And finally you have to ensure that your data is loaded through the `Reader` for the nested records to be read -- simply put, that means through a `Proxy`. So with the `load` method of a store, it will work while with any other way it will probably not (for example the `loadData` method of the store doesn't use the proxy).

Comment: -1, why go through all that when you can just specify the incoming date format on the model.

Comment: Because I think that the XTemplate system and the data view do not support model hasMany associations. Do they?

Comment: Templates don't, views do, but it doesn't matter. The OP is still getting the data from the model.